# Pyarrow Unable to Recognize Map Data Type

Tags: python, apache-spark, dask, parquet, pyarrow

There is some data that was stored in parquet file format that I want to read in using Dask. Unfortunately, it's not able to interpret the `map` data type. Is there a way to read in this data without relying on Spark? I am using `pyarrow==6.0.1`

**Example:**

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
df = dd.read_parquet("s3://data/part=0", engine='pyarrow')
df.compute()
```

**Error:**

```
ArrowNotImplementedError: Not implemented type for Arrow list to pandas: map<string, double>
```

Comment: update pyarrow to latest version..

Comment: https://github.com/apache/arrow/pull/6532

Comment: That didn't work. I'm using `pyarrow=7.0` now and that would be the latest version

Comment: Looks like you solved your issue [here](https://github.com/apache/arrow/issues/12396)?

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if this will work on your case (having a reproducible snippet could help), but a basic `delayed` wrapper might help, something like this:

```py
@delayed
def custom_load(file_path):
    # xx could be pandas, pyarrow or something else that opens the file without a problem
    df = xx.open_file(file_path) 
    ...
    return df

df = dd.from_delayed([custom_load(f) for f in list_files])
```